# Can't install PyOpenGL-accelerate - gcc failed with exit code 1

Tags: python, gcc, pip

Trying to `pip install p5`, failing to install the dependency `PyOpenGL-accelerate`.
When I try manually `pip install PyOpenGl-accelerate`, it fails with a [giant error log](https://gist.github.com/michaelmoreno/42b78a6af645f1447e20c34f843b5c7b) with one of the errors towards the end being:

```
    /usr/include/python3.10/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
      446 | static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
          |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
    ----------------------------------------
```

I've installed `gcc` already. Am using Arch linux.

Comment: `Python 3.10` is very new version and some modules may not be ready for this version. Better wait few months and use `3.9` or `3.8`

Comment: did you check if `/usr/bin/gcc` works in console.? OR maybe it needs to install some C/C++ modules - ie. `python-dev` with C/C++ headers for Python code.

Comment: Still having this after a year.  On Xubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 1):

Okay, So I request you to uninstall 3.10 version of python and install previous one. Because it's a new one so it might give you some error and maybe in trouble to install any library.

Follow this steps:
`python -m pip uninstall p5`
`reinstall python 3.8 or lesser version.`
`python -m pip install p5`

Comment: I'm having the same problem with `p5`. I can't downgrade my python, so I'll have to patiently wait.

Comment: you can use a python virtual environment with an older version of python... without having to downgrade the global python version